# F# Namespace not defined

Tags: build, reference, f#, namespaces

my F# project, working up til now, started erroring on:

> Error 54  The namespace 'Vision' is not defined

I've include some images from Visual Studio that show the situation:

[image: Start of program showing errors highlighted]

[image: Error messages]

[image: References from F# Project]
[image: Object Browser: browsing the missing references]

SO, I don't get why this built before and now won't build.  The refs are there, the namespaces are in the refs.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you change the solution platform to something not supported by the TBSM assemblies?

Comment: Not necessarily the platform of the whole solution. It's enough to just have conflicting platforms between the consuming project and the consumed assemblies.

Comment: Did you build those projects first so that the DLLs exist?

Answer (score 3):

@brent - bingo.  I had it a .net 4.5.2 but the assemblies only support 4.5

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. If you had to downgrade your project from 4.5.2 to 4.5, then you haven't solved anything, because you should not have to do that.

Comment: that's exactly what I did, and it solved the problem.  Note that the assemblies are in another project managed by another team.  I just reference them

Comment: You should be able to use assemblies with lower version numbers, even down to version 2. Was there more errors, or warnings, than the ones you showed in your question?

Comment: @brent -- just the ones I posted, which vanished when I changed the project from 4.5.2 to 4.5